# Run-time error "istreambuf_iterator is not dereferencable"

Tags: c++, search, visual-c++

Below is an example where I try to find a needle "8.0.4" whithin the text in addreses.txt. I use search from the algorithm library. However I get a runtime error on the search line (debug assertion failed) saying that **"Expression: istreambuf_iterator is not dereferencable"**

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("address.txt");
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iter(file);
    std::string needle = "8.0.4";

    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iter2 = std::search(iter, eos, needle.begin(), needle.end());

    return 0;
}
```

I have verified that the file is read correctly, by iterating through it using a simple while loop. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know it this is the reason, but the [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) function wants [forward iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator), which can handle multiple passes, but [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) is a *single pass* iterator.

Comment: Thanks, that might very well be the issue here. I'm gonna try and use std::find instead!